# Continuity of simplex

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose f and g are paths in a space X withf(1)=g(0).Now we want to construct a 2-simplex such that on the edges the simplex restricts to f,g and f*g.

Now the construction goes as put f on (e_0,e_1) and g on 
(e_1,e_2).Now we extend the map on whole simplex as keeping the simplex constant on the line perpendicular on the edge (e_0,e_2)

Now my question is what assures the continuity of simplex?(my guess is some form of pasting lemma)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p:\Delta^2 \rightarrow \Delta^1=[0,1]$ be the projection of the sides $e_0e_1$ and $e_1e_2$ onto the side $e_0e_2$. It is continuous, since it is the restriction of the projection onto a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. Let $g*f:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ denote the composite path. Then your simplex is given by the composite $$\Delta^2 \xrightarrow{p} [0,1] \xrightarrow{g*f} X$$, which is continuous as composition of continuous maps.